# python subprocess.check_output doesn't return when cat | grep combination

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on a raspberry pi and wanted to extract `cpuinfo` from `/proc/cpuinfo`with Python. This is the following command I want to execute:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'model name\|Hardware\|Serial' | uniq
```

I get the following output when I run the command directly on the Raspberry pi terminal :

```
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
Hardware        : BCM2835
Serial          : 0000000083a747d7
```

which is what I expect as well. I want to get this into a Python list, so I used the `subprocess.check_output()` method and used a `.split()` and `.splitlines()` considering the way it is formatted. But invoking the same command by using `subprocess.check_output()` I do not get what I expect. Here's the code I ran in Python :

```
import subprocess
items = [s.split('\t: ') for s in subprocess.check_output(["cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'model name\|Hardware\|Serial' | uniq "], shell=True).splitlines()]
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Trying to debug issue:
1)On removing the `.splitlines()` at the end. ie:

```
items = [s.split('\t: ') for s in subprocess.check_output(["cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'model name\|Hardware\|Serial' | uniq "], shell=True)
```

Now the Output error is:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

2)On removing `.split`:

```
items = [s for s in subprocess.check_output(["cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'model name\|Hardware\|Serial' | uniq "], shell=True)
```

Output `items` now holds the following:

```
>>> items
```

[109, 111, 100, 101, 108, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 9, 58, 32, 65, 82, 77, 118, 55, 32, 80, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 111, 114, 32, 114, 101, 118, 32, 52, 32, 40, 118, 55, 108, 41, 10, 72, 97, 114, 100, 119, 97, 114, 101, 9, 58, 32, 66, 67, 77, 50, 56, 51, 53, 10, 83, 101, 114, 105, 97, 108, 9, 9, 58, 32, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 56, 51, 97, 55, 52, 55, 100, 55, 10]

Almost seems like `grep` is behaving differently than I expect it. but I'm not able to zero-in on what exactly is the problem. What are these numbers? Is it values that grep returns? Please help on how to resolve.

Thanks

Comment: just read the `/proc/cpuinfo` and parse it in python

Comment: @AlexP. You're right! Its a duplicate. I did a lot of searching but never came across that post. That answer works. Should I update the answer here ?

Comment: also the `cat | grep` is an anti-pattern on its own. `grep` takes the input file name as a parameter - there is no need to spawn multiple processes for that. still in this case the best way is to just use python built-in file IO instead of subprocess

Comment: @AlexP. You're right. I was just thinking on debugging this problem rather than on another approach. IO would definitely be easy! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare with:

```
items = dict(s.split('\t: ') for s in open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r').read().splitlines() if s.startswith(('model name', 'Hardware', 'Serial')))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 the `subprocess.check_output()` returns `bytes` which need to be decoded to the `string` before string functions could be used. Another option is to use the legacy `subprocess.getoutput()` function.

The following code does the job for me:

```
items = [s.split('\t: ') for s in subprocess.getoutput(["cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'model name\|Hardware\|Serial' | uniq "]).splitlines()]
```